# Better code highlighting support in VS 2015?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, themes, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to achieve more sophisticated syntax highlighting in VS 2015? Specifically, I want to specify different colors for JS function names, function parameters, operators, and braces. Basically, I want to turn this:

[image: VS 2015 screenshot with poor highlighting]

into this:

[image: VS Code screenshot with good highlighting]

As you can see, the VS Code screenshot on the bottom has separate colors for the function name and parameters. However, I would also like to color the operators a different color as well similar to Sublime Text.

I already know about the "Fonts and Colors" tab in the Options menu, however it lumps functions, variables, etc. into "identifiers" and it lumps operators and braces into "operators," which doesn't serve my purpose well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the Viasfora extension.

Comment: +1 because the extension you recommended works great and might be what other people are looking for, however this extension does not support most of the features I requested